# Content control, ContentTemplateSelector, how to choose a staticresource based on value comming through binding, without datatriggers

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, staticresource

In a resource dictionary, I have few Viewboxes, and a datatemplate which has content control in it. I’m using style to switch between the viewboxes like this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="foo">
    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Viewbox}" Value="SageCashYes">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource SageCashYesViewbox}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Viewbox}" Value="SageCashNo">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource SageCashNoViewbox}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Is there anyway to do something like this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="foo">
      <ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{Binding Viewbox}" >
</DataTemplate>
```

So I’d like to be able to tell it to choose appropriate Viewbox based on this binding but without these data triggers?

I’m asking it because the view boxes have vectors inside to draw images, and these data trigger will grow huge in no time. So if there is something out there which will make my life easier I’d like to know about it.

**EDIT**

```
     <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Foo}
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
   </ListBox>

   public class MyViewModel
   {
   public MyViewModel()
       {
          MyList = new List<MyList>()
          {
            new MyItem() {BoolValue = false, Heading = "Bank Payment", Viewbox = "SageCashNo"},
            new MyItem() {BoolValue = true, Heading = "Cash Payment", Viewbox = "SageCashYes"}
          };
       }        

         public List<MyItem> MyList { get; set; }
       }

     public class MyItem
     {
          public bool {BoolValue { get; set; }
          public string Heading { get; set; }
          public string Viewbox { get; set; }
     }
```

Kind Regards 
Daniel

Comment: Would [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) help you?

Comment: From what I understand, it would allow me to move the decision logic to c# instead. So it want really help, because its still the same issue, I need to check the Binding Viewbox Value, and then based on that choose the Viewbox. I just though there maybe a way, of doing that without telling it, which viewbox to use, because it already has the mane of it.

Comment: Well in this case could you show the code where you are using the `<DataTemplate x:Key="foo">`? Because I can see it's declaration and not the usage without it it's hard to say what you can do really.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Hi, Thank your for your answer, and excuse me for late reply, but I had to stop it for few days and do something else. I added the code you asked about in an Edit part. Kind Regards

Comment: If you want the content to be automatic depending on the Content, then you shouldn't use the string to do that as you will have to at some point define which values are appropriate i.e. [TemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in `C#`. If however you want to put some effort into it you could define the `Type` of the `ViewBox` property as a custom class and then use that class as a definition for your `DataTemplate` as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). HTH

Comment: @XAMlMAX I looked at the article, but Im not able to figure out how to do it. Adding this <local:MyItem x:Key="MyItem"/> and then this DataType="{x:Type local:MyItem}" does not help. instead of viewbox I'm getting back text :(. Small code sample would be really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What I meant is that instead of `string ViewBox` property you would use `CustomClass ViewBox` then when you define `DataTemplate` you would use it like so: `DataType="{x:Type local:CustomClass}"` hope this makes sense. I should mention that you would need to create separate class for every type of ViewBox you need.

Comment: @XAMlMAX it make sense now. I've got lots of these viewboxes, so I probably should stay with these datatriggers. Thank you for clarification. Regards